# Apply AllowOverride in global for all files conf of apache2

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, configuration, webserver

Is it possible to apply the `AllowOverride` directive globally? (without, therefore, going to every single configuration file and adding the directive)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, directives in a `<Directory>` container are inherited to child directories. You could set the "global" setting for a parent directory of all your document roots, e.g. `/var/www` (if your `DocumentRoot`s are `/var/www/html`, `/var/www/example.com` etc.).

Example: Modified `/var/www` in `apache.conf` (Debian), default is `AllowOverride None`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        # commented the default behaviour
        #AllowOverride None

        # new setting, only set the types you need, e.g. AuthConfig, FileInfo etc.
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Of course you have to make sure that there are no other `<Directory>` directives below this directory which reset the setting to `None` again.

For fine-tuning which individual directives are allowed in `.htaccess` files, see the [AllowOverrideList](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist) directive.

Comment: (```/``` and ```/var/www``` are the same thing, right?) So, since I have everything in ```/var/www``` (**folder1** and all subfolders, **folders2**, etc.), if I set this directive in the configuration file (which I renamed to ```000-name.conf``` to get it launched "**first** ") and also **outside of any ```VirtualHost```**, will it be inherited from all other configuration files? (as long as they don't change this directive ... but this doesn't happen)

Comment: `/` is the root of your filesystem, I wouldn't enable anything for that directory. Set the directive in your main Apache config (`apache.conf`, `httpd.conf`) and it's inherited in all your vhosts. If you set it in a vhost, then it's only enabled in that vhost.

Comment: Thanks...is there a way to check if the actual directive function or not? (in the file log apache?)

Comment: For most modules you need a more verbose [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) (debug or one of the trace levels). But you can enable per-module logging, something like `LogLevel info ssl:debug rewrite:trace3` for a general `info` level, `debug` for `mod_ssl` and `trace3` for `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: If `AllowOverride` is set to `None`, then `.htaccess` files are completely ignored. But if you enable one specific type of directives and use a directive that is not enabled (e.g. `AuthConfig` is enabled and you use `RewriteEngine On` which needs `FileInfo` enabled), you'll get an internal server error and the error is logged if you load a page from that directory. There's an option `Nonfatal=...` you can additionally set to treat those errors as non-fatal (errors are logged, but no HTTP 500 error).